# Unable to do HTTP POST from J2ME (Nokia S40 6thEdition)

Tags: java, java-me

Im unable to do HTTP POST using J2ME below is the code that im using which is throwing an exception when I try and write to the OutputStrem.

In the code Below SYSO prints "here5". Please need some guidance. Basically I've put the http connection part in a separate threads run method, to keep it aloof from the UI thread.

```
public void run(){
    HttpConnection http = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    String msg = "lat=10&long=20&mac=923873";
    try{
    String url = "http://xxxx.php"; 
    byte[] data = null;
    InputStream istrm = null;

    http = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("here1");
    }
    try
    {
        http.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("here2");
    }

    try{
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "HttpMidlet/0.2");
        http.setRequestProperty("Custom-Property", "MyCustomProperty/1.0; AnotherProperty/debug_0.1");

        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+msg.getBytes().length);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("here3");
    }

    try{

        out = http.openOutputStream();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("here4");
    }
    try{
    out.write(msg.getBytes());
    out.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("here5");
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `DataOutputStream` Class.

Comment: Verify this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650199/upload-a-wav-file-using-j2me/11566328#11566328

Comment: Still unable to resolve this error "0-Error in HTTP operation"

Comment: **1)** replace `System.out.println("here1")` with `System.out.println("here1, [" + e + "])` **2)** do the same for all remaining four `println`s **3)** re-run your test **4)** update your question with improved log message printed instead of cryptic "here5"

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
     * Send the data to the URL of Server Site using the POST connection.
     * 
     * @return the response of server.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public byte[] send() throws Exception {
        HttpConnection hc = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] res = null;

        try {
            hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);

            hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + getBoundaryString());

            hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);



            OutputStream dout = hc.openOutputStream();

            dout.write(postBytes);
            if (dout!=null) {
                dout.close();
                dout = null;
            }

            int ch;
            is = hc.openInputStream();

            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(ch);
            }
            res = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // if an error occurred connecting to the server.
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            try {
                if (bos != null)
                    bos.close();

                if (is != null)
                    is.close();

                if (hc != null)
                    hc.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the code. Tried it but still getting the same error "0-Error in HTTP operation"

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Nokia Sample](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_Http_POST_request_in_Java_ME) you do not need to call `setRequestProperty` methods.

Another interesting point is the usage of `Connector.open(urlstring, Connector.READ_WRITE)`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the link. Tried it but still getting the same error "0-Error in HTTP operation"

Comment: Please, do as @gnat said in the question comments. Change your debug messages to get more info on the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by re-installing the emulator.